# Download Private video from URL and play only from React Native App (Not From Android File Explorer / Gallery )

Tags: android, react-native, encryption, react-native-video

how can we encrypt video downloaded from url so that it wont be available from mobile file explorer like youtube save video feature
i tried this article but it didn't tells how to encrypt video

[how-to-download-private-videos-in-react-native-app](https://codingmojo.in/how-to-download-private-videos-in-react-native-app)

i am using react-native-video package to display video in react native app,& video is stored on digital ocean spaces